# What is the runtime of this pseudo-code

Tags: runtime, pseudocode, discrete-mathematics

```
i = 1;  
while (i <= n)
   j = i;  
   x = x+A[i];  
   while (j > 0)  
     y = x/(2*j);  
     j = j/2; // Assume here that this returns the floor of the quotient  
   i = 2*i;
return y;
```

I'm not sure about my answer, I got O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets remove `x` and `y` variables because it doesn't affect to complexity.

```
i = 1;  
while (i <= n)
   j = i;    
   while (j > 0)  
      j = j/2;  
   i = 2*i;
```

1. In the inner loop you every time divide `j` by 2, so actually it is not liner it is `O(logn)`. For example when `j` is 16 you will do 5 `( O(log16)+1 )` steps: 8,4,2,1,0.
2. In the outer loop you every time multiply `i` by 2, so it is also `O(logn)`.

So overall complexity will be `O(logn * logn)`.